# Chapter titles in the Header of a document generated by Asciidoctor-PDF

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'd need to add the Chapter title in the page's heading of PDF files generated with Asciidoctor-toPDF.
Here is the set of Properties I'm using at the beginning of my doc:

```
= Book title
:notitle:
:toc: left
:toclevels: 8 
:sectnums:
:sectnumlevels: 8
:source-highlighter: coderay 
:icons: font
:chapter-label:
:header_recto_content_center: '{section-title}'
```

Is there any property I am missing or which conflicts with the Header generation?

Answer (score 2):

A few [theme-related attributes](http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-asciidoctor%2Fasciidoctor-pdf%2F%2Fdocs%2Ftheming-guide.adoc#theme-related-document-attributes) exist. But `header` is not one of them unfortunately.

So to style the header of a PDF one must resort to a custom style in YAML format.

#### Style

For this example the file is named `style.yml` and placed in our working directory.

```yaml
extends: default   #1

header:
  height: 15mm     #2
  recto: &header   #3
    center-content: '-- {section-or-chapter-title} --' #4
  verso: *header   #5
```

1. Extends the default `asciidoctor-pdf` theme with your customized code.
2. Define the height of the header or the content will not show; also explained [here](http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-asciidoctor%2Fasciidoctor-pdf%2F%2Fdocs%2Ftheming-guide.adoc#keys-running-content).
3. Create a YAML anchor to the whole content of `recto`.
4. The use of `{section-or-chapter-title}` is explained and shown at the end of the post.
5. Reference the content from `&header`. In plain make `verso` behave the same as `recto`.

#### Document

The content of the adoc file is as shown below. The file is aptly named `book.adoc` and placed in the same directory as `style.yml`.

```
= Book title
:notitle:
:toc: left
:toclevels: 8 
:sectnums:
:sectnumlevels: 8
:source-highlighter: coderay 
:icons: font
:chapter-label:

== Chapter One

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua.

== Chapter Two

=== Section One

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua.
```

#### Conversion

PDF conversion is done using the `pdf-stylesdir` and `pdf-style` attributes.

```sh
asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-stylesdir=. -a pdf-style=style.yml -d book book.adoc
```

#### Result

Chapter one looks then as shown in the screenshot. As there is no section header the chapter is used to populate the header.

[image]

Chapter two having both a chapter and a section defined is displaying the section title in the header.

[image]